# App Icons for Apps on SD Card Disappear on Reboot

Tags: reboot, 7.1-nougat, internal-sd, motorola

I have a Motorola Moto E4 running Nougat 7.1.1, security patch level of March 1, 2018. The phone has a 16GB SD card in it, which is installed as internal storage, not portable, and it has a number of apps on it. As far as I know, the phone has always behaved in the following fashion: whenever I reboot, any app installed on the SD card has its icon disappear from the home screen. I can get it back, but a reboot happens often enough that this is an annoyance. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I would believe that the REBOOT should be the bigger annoyance. A well-performing device should rarely need a reboot. I don't recall the last time I performed one that was not sysupdate-related.

Comment: Does those app icons seen in green android icons? Maybe your SD card got ejected.

Comment: @RahulGopi on a reboot, it definitely got ejected :) I've no experience with adoptable storage, but this issue was quite common with "portable storage" – as the SD card is mounted *after* the `BOOT_COMPLETED` event is propagated. On the same event, the launcher is started; so if the latter was initialized faster than the SD card was (checked and) mounted, that's exactly what happend: the launcher couldn't access the "not-ready" card, and thus marked those apps "missing". Not sure how this is handled by today's adoptable storage, though.

Comment: @wbogacz: Oh, these are sysupdate-related reboots. I can't remember the last time I rebooted for any other reason.

Comment: @Rahul Gopi: Nope, all the icons look normal. The apps are all there, and as far as I know, Android knows they're all there. The apps themselves are not disappearing, only their icons.

Comment: @Izzy: That's certainly a plausible theory, even for internal storage as opposed to portable. Is there a way to change the boot sequence slightly, or to enforce the correct boot order?

Comment: @AdrianKeister the boot order is not the issue, just the "premature" `BOOT_COMPLETED`. I wouldn't know how to change that; I rather had the feeling that event might trigger mounting the card ("removable media" being counted as "user-space things"). Not sure about that, though.

Answer (score -1):

Those Apps which icon get lost after ejection of the `SD Card` are actually in the `SD card` and when you take `SD card` out of your `Mobile`, `android` is not able to find the specific App in its system. Thats why `Android` is not able to show the icons of the Apps. For getting out of this problem kindly go o Settings>Application Manager. Move all your apps to `Phone Storage` from SD card by opening each Application and selection Move to `Phone Storage`

Comment: I'm afraid you have completely misunderstood my problem. I have not removed the SD Card at all. Android recognizes every single app on the SD Card at all times throughout this whole process. Your answer is therefore irrelevant.